# C++ - Read input file and store and calculate statistics

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I posted a question on this topic earlier when I was beginning the problem. Since then, I have worked on the source code and filled in a lot of blanks. I have experiencing some troubles now, because there are a lot of discrepancies and problems with my source code.

Please ignore the comments. I include them for my own personal benefit as they help remind me of what I am doing or what is going on especially when I am checking my own work.

First, it has 9 function prototypes that are categorized into 3 groups with 3 methods each that do the same thing but for different variables. For example, `int getFirstLowest(StudentData[])` `int getFirstHighest(StudentData[])`, and `double getAverage1(StudentData[], int)`. I want a different method to find the lowest, highest and average of each exam and the lowest, highest and average value of the totals of each. An idea that I had was to create an array of size 3 for each statistic I need to calculate (lowest, highest, average and standard deviation), but I don't know how to do it.

Next, I am curious if I should just combine my `getTotal` function and `getGrades` function to be more efficient. The `getTotal` method just adds up all the exam scores while the `getGrades` is just filled with if else statements to categorize the scores and determine their grades.

In addition, I also need some help with the `print` function. My output needs to look similar to the image I attached below, but it doesn't. The count for each student turns out wrong and starts at 0 and messes up my alignment which is why I did not include it.

Here is an image of how my output should look like: 
[image]

Here is an image of my current output: 
[image]

I printed the lowest, highest, and average data at the top to check if my calculations were correct for each aspect as I am still unsure how to place the data into an array to print it out more smoothly. In addition, please note that some of the data in both images are the same and are different, because the first image is a sample from a previous semester. My numbers are correct in the exam columns.

---

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <string> 
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iomanip> 

    using namespace std; 

    struct StudentData
    {
        int studentID; 
        string first_name; 
        string last_name; 
        int exam1; 
        int exam2; 
        int exam3; 
        int total; 
        char ch; 
    }; 

    istream& operator >> (istream& in, StudentData& st)
    {
        return (in >> st.studentID
                   >> st.first_name
                   >> st.last_name
                   >> st.exam1
                   >> st.exam2
                   >> st.exam3);
    }

    const int SIZE = 9; 

    // Function prototypes
    void openInputFile(ifstream &, string); 
    int getFirstLowest(StudentData[]); 
    int getSecondLowest(StudentData[]); 
    int getThirdLowest(StudentData[]); 
    int getFirstHighest(StudentData[]); 
    int getSecondHighest(StudentData[]); 
    int getThirdHighest(StudentData[]); 
    double getAverage1(StudentData[], int); 
    double getAverage2(StudentData[], int); 
    double getAverage3(StudentData[], int); 
    void getTotal(StudentData arr[]); 
    void getGrade(StudentData arr[]); 
    void print(StudentData[]); 

    int main()
    {
        // Variables
        //standardDeviation;  
        StudentData arr[SIZE]; 
        int x, y, z, w; // Stores lowest exam scores
        int i, j, k, l; // Holds highest exam scores
        double average1, average2, average3, average4; // Represents average of each exam 

    int lowest[3]; 
    int highest[3]; 
    double average[3]; 

    ifstream inFile; 
    string inFileName = "C:\\Users\\Lisa\\Desktop\\scores.txt"; 

    // Call function to read data in file
    openInputFile(inFile, inFileName);

    // Read data into an array of structs 
    size_t numItems = 0;
    while (inFile >> arr[numItems])
    {
        ++numItems;
    }

    // Close input file
    inFile.close();  

    // Get lowest exam scores from each exam
    x = getFirstLowest(arr); 
    y = getSecondLowest(arr); 
    z = getThirdLowest(arr); 

    // Get highest exam scores from each exam 
    i = getFirstHighest(arr); 
    j = getSecondHighest(arr); 
    k = getThirdHighest(arr); 

    cout << "\nLowest exam scores (in order): " << x << " " << y << " " << z << endl; 
    cout << "\nHighest exam scores (in order): " << i << " " << j << " " << k << endl; 

    cout << "\n"; 

    // Get average score of each exam 
    average1 = getAverage1(arr, SIZE); 
    average2 = getAverage2(arr, SIZE); 
    average3 = getAverage3(arr, SIZE); 

    cout << "Exam 1 Average: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << average1 << endl; 
    cout << "Exam 2 Average: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << average2 << endl; 
    cout << "Exam 3 Average: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << average3 << endl; 

    cout << "\n"; 

    getTotal(arr); 

    getGrade(arr); 

    print(arr); 

    system("PAUSE"); 

    return 0; 
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
void openInputFile(ifstream &inFile, string inFileName)
{
    //Open the file
    inFile.open(inFileName);

    //Input validation
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Error to open file." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
int getFirstLowest(StudentData arr[])
{
    int lowest = 0; 
    int num = arr[0].exam1; 

    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (num > arr[i].exam1)
        {
            num = arr[i].exam1; 
            lowest = i; 
        }
    }
    return num;
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
int getSecondLowest(StudentData arr[])
{
    int lowest = 0; 
    int num = arr[0].exam2; 

    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (num > arr[i].exam2)
        {
            num = arr[i].exam2; 
            lowest = i; 
        }
    }
    return num;
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
int getThirdLowest(StudentData arr[])
{
    int lowest = 0; 
    int num = arr[0].exam3; 

    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (num > arr[i].exam3)
        {
            num = arr[i].exam3; 
            lowest = i; 
        }
    }
    return num;
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
int getFirstHighest(StudentData arr[])
{
    int highest = 0; 
    int num = arr[0].exam1; 

    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (num < arr[i].exam1)
        {
            num = arr[i].exam1; 
            highest = i; 
        }
    }
    return num;
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
int getSecondHighest(StudentData arr[])
{
    int highest = 0; 
    int num = arr[0].exam2; 

    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (num < arr[i].exam2)
        {
            num = arr[i].exam2; 
            highest = i; 
        }
    }
    return num;
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
int getThirdHighest(StudentData arr[])
{
    int highest = 0; 
    int num = arr[0].exam3; 

    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (num < arr[i].exam3)
        {
            num = arr[i].exam3; 
            highest = i; 
        }
    }
    return num;
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
double getAverage1(StudentData arr[], int size)
{
    int sum = 0; 
    double average = 0; 

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i].exam1; 
    }

    average += static_cast<double>(sum)/size; 

    return average; 
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
double getAverage2(StudentData arr[], int size)
{
    int sum = 0; 
    double average = 0; 

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i].exam2; 
    }

    average += static_cast<double>(sum)/size; 

    return average; 
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
double getAverage3(StudentData arr[], int size)
{
    int sum = 0; 
    double average = 0; 

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i].exam3; 
    }

    average += static_cast<double>(sum)/size; 

    return average; 
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
void getTotal(StudentData arr[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        arr[i].total = arr[i].exam1 + arr[i].exam2 + arr[i].exam3; 
    }
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
void getGrade(StudentData arr[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i].total >= 270)
            arr[i].ch = 'A'; 
        else if(arr[i].total >= 240)
            arr[i].ch = 'B'; 
        else if(arr[i].total >= 210)
            arr[i].ch = 'C'; 
        else if(arr[i].total >= 180)
            arr[i].ch = 'D'; 
        else 
            arr[i].ch = 'F'; 
    }
}

/**
* Pre-condition: 
* Post-condition: 
*/
void print(StudentData arr[])
{
    cout << "ID First Name  Last Name   Exam1   Exam2   Exam3   Total   Grade" << endl; 
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << left << arr[i].studentID << "\t" << setw(10) <<  arr[i].first_name << "\t" << setw(5) << arr[i].last_name << "\t\t" 
             << arr[i].exam1 << "\t" << arr[i].exam2 << "\t" << arr[i].exam3 << "\t" << arr[i].total << "\t" << arr[i].ch << endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use some more data types (i.e., classes or structs) to help you capture/compute all the information you need (in a simple/easy way), see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29872524/4505712) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> First, it has 9 function prototypes that are categorized into 3 groups with 3 methods each that do the same thing but for different variables.

This is not very extensible (i.e., because of all the work involved, meaning code changes, when new exam scores and/or students are add). Perhaps you're already aware of this since you made the following statement.

> I want a different method to find the lowest, highest and average of each exam and the lowest, highest and average value of the totals of each.

---

Since this is a learning assignment I can show you my output, my main, and my skeleton implementation. If it looks like something you were trying to do then you can finish implementing the skeleton code. **Note**, I didn't try to get the formatting exact since it should be easy enough for you.

### My Output

```
1234            David           Dalton          82              86              80              248
9138            Shirley         Gross           90              98              94              282
3124            Cynthia         Morley          87              84              82              253
4532            Albert          Roberts         56              89              78              223
5678            Amelia          Pauls           90              87              65              242
6134            Samson          Smith           29              65              33              127
7874            Michael         Garett          91              92              92              275
8026            Melissa         Downey          74              75              89              238
9893            Gabe            Yu              69              66              68              203

                                Lowest:         29              65              33              127
                                Higest:         91              98              94              283
                                Avg:            74.2222         82.4444         75.6667         232.333
```

### My main

The implementation is pretty straight-forward/simple.

```
int main()
{
    Students students;
    Exams exams;

    // Read data from file and populate all student and exam data structures
    if (!initialize(students, exams))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // Compute all the exam statistics
    exams.computeStatistics();

    // Print all the student information
    for (const auto& student : students)
    {
        std::cout << student << "\n";
    }

    // Print the exam information
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << exams << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

### Skeleton Code

Here is a skeleton of the code I used which may be helpful to you.

```
// A class to represent a single exam
class Exam
{
public:
    // Computes min, max, and avg (later can be extended to compute
    // additional statistics)
    void computeStatistics()
    {
        // TODO
    }

    int min() const { return mMin; }
    int max() const { return mMax; }
    double avg() const { return mAvg; }

    // Adds a score earned by a student (i.e., keeps track of all scores
    // which are used by the 'computeStatistics' function)
    void addScore(int score)
    {
        // TODO
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> mScores; // All scores for this exam

    // Values computed for all available scores
    int mMin;
    int mMax;
    double mAvg;
};

// A class to represent all exams (this is helpful since there are some
// statistics that need to be computed for all exams)
class Exams
{
public:
    // Get the exam associated with the specified exam numer
    Exam& operator[](std::size_t examNumber)
    {
        return mExams[examNumber];
    }

    // Compute min total, max total, average average, store all exam min
    // scores, store all exam max scores, store all exam avg scores
    void computeStatistics()
    {
        // TODO
    }

    // Prints the exam information (e.g., Lowest, Highest, Average)
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Exams& exams)
    {
        // TODO
    }

private:
    // Mapping from 'exam number' to the exam data type
    std::map<int, Exam> mExams;

    // Stores all min, max, and avg exam scores (for printing later)
    std::vector<int> mMinScores;
    std::vector<int> mMaxScores;
    std::vector<double> mAvgScores;

    // Values computed for all available exams
    int mMinTotal;
    int mMaxTotal;
    double mAvgAvg;
};

// Class to represent a student
class Student
{
public:
    Student() :
        mTotalScore(0)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    // Records a student's score on a particular exam (this is also used
    // to keep a running total of all exam scores for this student, which
    // can be printed later)
    void addScore(int examNumber, int score)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    // Each exam score for this student is added to 'exams'
    void updateExams(Exams& exams) const
    {
        // TODO
    }

    int mId;
    std::string mFirstName;
    std::string mLastName;

    // Mapping from 'exam number' to exam score
    std::map<int, int> mExams;
    int mTotalScore; // Total of all exam scores for this student
};

// Reads a student from a stream (hint: uses the 'addScore' function)
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Student& student)
{
    // TODO
}

// Prints out a student (i.e., id, fist, last, exam1, exam2, exam3, examTotal)
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Student& student)
{
    // TODO
}

// Just an alias so that you don't have to type 'std::vector<Student>' all over
using Students = std::vector<Student>;

// Reads all the data from the text file and adds each student to 'students'
// and each exam to 'exams' (hint: after each student is read it can be
// used to update all the exams)
bool initialize(Students& students, Exams& exams)
{
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Unfortunately, I cannot use classes in my code since my professor has not introduced them to the class yet.

Comment: That's a shame because they can make it much easier... If it makes any difference you can replace all occurrences of `class` with `struct`. I thought it would be okay since you were already using a `struct`.

Comment: If I create a struct with the lowest, highest, average, and standard deviation, when I calculate them, I just pass the StudentData arr[] right?

Comment: Yes, you could convert all the classes to structs, remove their functions (making them regular functions), and convert any C++ types (e.g., `std::vector`, `std::map`) to types you're allowed to use. Then you could use the functions by passing the appropriate structs (or arrays of structs) to them.

Comment: Please upload some input data so new users like me can run the code.